# React.js checkbox changes property in state to 'on'

Tags: reactjs, checkbox, state

I could use some help understanding what's going on here. I'm learning React, and trying to recreate a component I've built in an existing app in Ember.

Fairly simple case, just have a component that has its own state, and this component includes a checkbox to toggle a property, `starChart`, on the state. The problem is that though the checkbox gets the right value from state, when I toggle it, it stays checked and changes the state property to the string "on" instead of a boolean.

**Here's the checkbox**; I followed another tutorial in creating the `onChange` call and the handler function, so there's probably something wrong here, I just don't know how to tell what it is:

```
<input name="starChart" 
       type="checkbox" 
       checked={data.starChart} 
       onChange={(e) => this.handleChange(e)}/>
```

**handler function**

```
  handleChange = (e) => {
    const rec = {
      ...this.state.dci,
      [e.target.name]: e.target.value
    };
    this.setState({dci: rec});  
  }
```

I've had a similar issue with inputs that should be numbers, but it seems an `<input>` in React always returns some string, and I'm not sure how to coerce it to the type (boolean, integer, etc) that I want.

Answer (score 0):

In your state you can store the input's state. Once the change event occurs, you can toggle the state's value.

Here is an example code:

```
class Input extends React.Component {
    constructor(props) {
        super(props);

        this.state = {
            // Default value of the input
            checked: false
        }

        this.toggleChange = this.toggleChange.bind(this);
    }

    toggleChange() {
        this.setState({
            checked: ! this.state.checked
        });
    }

    render() {
        <input checked = {this.state.checked} onChange = {this.toggleChange} />
    }
}
```

Comment: So you have to create a custom `input` component just to mimic how an HTML input acts?

Comment: In case of reusability - yes. It's not required. You can handle it any other component, but if you want to reuse it - it's better to separate it as a stand alone component.